# Remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons

Tags: server, ssh, xubuntu, firewall, google

I am newbie to Google Cloud. I tried to access my Linux VM from RDP, but it is giving me the following error:

[image: error]

My firewall rules are as follows:

[image: firewall rules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot RDP into a Linux VM, you need to SSH.  Either use the built-in option in GCP or a terminal application like putty, WinSCP, etc....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RDP protocol to connect to Ubuntu instance on google cloud through Windows (pro), you can follow the following steps:

```
1. sudo apt update 
2. sudo apt install tasksel
3. sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
4. sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
5. sudo passwd root // set root password, if you don't remember it
6. sudo apt install xrdp
7. sudo systemctl enable xrdp // This will start RDP service
```

Now, open Remote Desktop Connection on Windows, put the I.P address, and connect. Use "root" as username and its password to log in.